# Magento 1: how to configure the first configuration which will be opened?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, extensions, configuration

I noticed this behavior several times on several websites I've worked on.

When clicking **System > Configuration** *the first configuration section that opens is not the first one of the list of tabs.*

I've **checked the sort order of the `system.xml` file of the module** related to this section but didn't find anything obvious.

So I assume *there may be some shady thing 3rd party modules vendors do to be sure their extension comes first when you open the configuration.*

**Where should I look at to investigate that behavior ?**

Comment: by "several times" you mean this cannot be reproduced always under the same conditions, or it happened after installing some modules, and while the module was installed this is always reproduceable.

Comment: @Marius it happened with different 3rd party modules on different Magento installs. I've never actually tried to reproduce the behavior by reinstalling the module that comes first in another install

Comment: @fschmengler well spotted thanks for that ;)